# Crystal master-detail reports with data in POCOs

Tags: crystal-reports, poco, subreport

OK, I've worked out how to do master/detail reports from POCO's by having my master data in one collection and detail records in another, and binding the master data collection to the main report and the detail records to a subreport, and telling Crystal how to link the details records to a master record.

However, that's not how my domain model objects are structured.  My objects look more like this:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }    
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }    
    public InvoiceLine[] Lines { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }    
    public int Quantity { get; set; }    
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use this structure as the data for a Crystal report, or do I really have to split the master and detail records into two separate collections?

Comment: `or do I really have to split the master and detail records into two separate collections?` -- Isn't that what you've done here?

Comment: No, what I've done here is to put each invoice's lines into its own collection inside the appropriate invoice, so there will be not two collections but N+1 of them, if there are N invoices.

Comment: OK.  So what's the "master" collection?

Comment: What I was hoping for was an event that was executed for each master record (and with the master record accessible) in which I could pass the appropriate detail records to the subreport.

Comment: I didn't declare it in the example.  It would be an Invoice[] or similar.

Comment: Yep.  That's what I think you need to do. It's either that, or invoke CR once for each invoice you want to print.